# Choose right capacitors for flyback design

Tags: capacitor, flyback, component-selection

Would like to build an flyback inverter from 12V to 100V power 250W.
The 12V source is a rectified generator.

I'm struggeling with the right primary capacitor selection.

I calculated a ripple current from the transformer around 83Appk.

If I look around, capacitors will have much lower ratings so that means that I have to set capacitors in parallel. But even in that case I need tens of capacitors.

What are my options in this case?

calculations:
based on:

https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/acdc/acdc_pwm/acdc_pwm01/940

[image]

[schematic of flyback design](https://diy-warmtepomp.nl/wp-content/uploads/flyback-converter-1.pdf)

Comment: 250 W is a lot for a flyback inverter.  Can you post your circuit and your calculations?

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: I agree with @evildemonic.  A single-switch flyback at 250W isn't impossible, but I'd look at other topologies for your requirements.

Comment: almost every notebook PSU is a flyback based design, is your post based on designs where the input voltage is as low as 12V?

Comment: Both my laptop power supplies are 130 watts and, generally, engineers (who might know) tend to say that anything more than 150 watts is looking less like a flyback and more like a forward converter, 250 watts is in forward converter country. What AC frequency does the generator produce? What is it's regulation like?

Comment: the generator produces 3ph sinewave around 30-200Hz respectively 8-16V. But voltage will drop when drawing power from it. The flyback is designed to dump power isolated to a solar inverter.

Comment: The bulk capacitors and, a lot of components on your schematic have values that are really hard to see. However, if it's any consolation, on one job I had 42 parallel capacitors, BTW, what transformer core are you using and what switching frequency?

Comment: 3.32 peak to average current ratio isn't unheard of in a flyback, but the 83 A ripple figure is when you should take a step back and not so much check if your calculations are correct but rather if the topology is suitable. Sounds to me like you need a push-pull converter, perhaps two-phase.

Comment: I moved some values for legibility. Please see schematic, but keep in mind that every value in the schematic is not fixed since I'm in the designing phase. The transformer core I selected is ETD59 with N87 material and 1.5mm gap. I think it is pretty heavy but first I have to see if copperwire will fit and everything will work properly.

Comment: (For improved current sharing, use 3(×2) source resistors (& separate wiring where appropriate).)